# Vector Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have $T$ defined by $T \textbf{x}=(\textbf{x} \cdot(3,2,1))(3,2,1)+(\textbf{x} \cdot(-1,0,-2))(-1,0,-2)  $

and the following questions:

[image]

I multiplied out the brackets to find the image $i=\begin{bmatrix}10 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $j=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 4\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $k=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}$ and standard matrix representation being $\begin{bmatrix}10 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 5\end{bmatrix}$ however I'm not sure if this right as I haven't encountered problems set out in that way.

Comment: You’ve certainly done something wrong in computing the images of the basis vectors, but it’s hard to say what without seeing more of your work. For a start, $(10,0,0)^T$ can't be the image of *any* vector since it’s not a linear combination of $(3,2,1)^T$ and $(-1,0,-2)^T$.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $\{\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Note that

- $T(\mathbf{i})=3(3,2,1)-(-1,0,-2)=(10,6,5)$;
- $T(\mathbf{j})=2(3,2,1)=(6,4,2)$;
- $T(\mathbf{k})=(3,2,1)-2(-1,0,-2)=(5,2,5)$.

So,$$A_T=\begin{bmatrix}10&6&5\\6&4&2\\5&2&5\end{bmatrix}.$$